# AFNetworking issue with response : unauthorized (401)

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, afnetworking, nsurlsession

I have used AFNetworking in my project, whenever i sent request,Im getting this message in failure block,

> Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011
>   "Request failed: unauthorized (401)"
>   UserInfo={com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=
>   com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.data=<7b227375 63636573
>   73223a66 616c7365 2c226d65 73736167 65223a22 41757468 656e7469
>   63617469 6f6e2066 61696c65 64227d>, NSLocalizedDescription=Request
>   failed: unauthorized (401)}

This is how I'm sending request by using AFNetworking.

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:BASE_URL]];

manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json", nil];

NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/api/##/##/##/sign_in"];

NSString *params = @"{\"user\": {\"uid\": \"10236412002551\",\"access_token\":\"g6tdbvc34seadcx7yufbbcgvf8ijhss\",\"email\": \"user@domain1.com\",\"latitude\": \"6.927079\",        \"longitude\": \"79.861243\",\"remote_avatar_url\": \"\"}}";

manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

AFSecurityPolicy* policy = [AFSecurityPolicy policyWithPinningMode:AFSSLPinningModeCertificate];
[policy setValidatesDomainName:NO];
[policy setAllowInvalidCertificates:YES];

[manager POST:path parameters:params success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
    if([[responseObject objectForKey:@"error_code"] intValue]==0){
        if (success) {
           success(userArray);
        }
     }
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
        if (failure) {
            failure(error);
        }
    }];
}
```

But If I will be able to get the correct response by using NSURLSession.(Please refer below code)

```
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: defaultConfigObject delegate: nil delegateQueue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];

    NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://##/api/##/##/##/sign_in"];
    NSMutableURLRequest * urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    NSString * params =@"{\"user\": {\"uid\": \"10236412002551\",\"access_token\":\"g6tdbvc34seadcx7yufbbcgvf8ijhss\",\"email\": \"user@domain1.com\",\"latitude\": 6.927079,        \"longitude\": 79.861243,\"remote_avatar_url\": \"\"}}";

    [urlRequest addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [urlRequest setHTTPBody:[params dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSURLSessionDataTask * dataTask =[defaultSession dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest
                                                       completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                                           NSLog(@"Response:%@ %@\n", response, error);
                                                           if(error == nil)
                                                           {
                                                               NSString * text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

                                                               NSDictionary * json  = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

                                                               NSLog(@"Data = %@",text);
                                                               NSLog(@"Data = %@",json);
                                                           }

                                                       }];
    [dataTask resume];
```

I'm interested in using AFNetworking,But due to this issue I won't be able to move forward. Please help me to correct the issue with AFNetworking.

This is the request I should send,

```
{ 
    "user": {
       "uid": "102364120025511",
       "access_token": "g6tdbvc34seadcx7yufbbcgaavf8ijh",
       "email": "user@domain.com",
       "latitude": 6.927079,
       "longitude": 79.861243,
       "remote_avatar_url": ""
    }
}
```

This is the response I should get,

```
{
  "success": true,
  "message": "Successfully authenticated",
  "user": {
    "id": 123,
    "email": "user@domain.com",
    "provider": "facebook",
    "latitude": 6.927079,
    "longitude": 79.861243,
    "avatar": {
      "url": "",
      "thumb": ""
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: BTW, if you're wondering what that `7b227375...` data contains, that is a JSON payload that says `{"success":false,"message":"Authentication failed"}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're providing your `params` as a JSON string and then instructing AFNetworking to use a `AFJSONRequestSerializer` to then represent that string in a JSON structure. The net effect is that you've JSONified this twice.

You should provide dictionary object and let AFNetworking create the JSON for you, e.g.:

```
NSString *params = @{@"user": @{@"uid": @"10236412002551", @"access_token": @"g6tdbvc34seadcx7yufbbcgvf8ijhss", @"email": @"user@domain1.com", @"latitude": @6.927079, @"longitude": @79.861243, @"remote_avatar_url": @""}};
```

By the way, letting AFNetworking (which uses `NSJSONSerialization`) build the JSON for you will be far more robust than your trying to do this yourself. So, even if you use the `NSURLSession` approach, I'd suggest building this nested dictionary structure and then using `NSJSONSerialization` to build the JSON data payload. Or, if you use AFNetworking, it will do this for you.

Comment: Great help bro @Rob, Thanks :)